# Symfony Circular relation reference issue

Tags: php, symfony4, circular-reference

I have following setup

```
Entity/User
---------------
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserGroup", mappedBy="users")
  */
  private $userGroups;


Entity/UserGroup
    ---------------
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userGroups")
  */
  private $users;
```

as you can see I have `manyTomany` bidirectional relation,

- a user belongs to multiple groups
- a group can have multiple users

when I serialize the relationship (in order to serve an API request),

I get deeply nested json object

```
$groups = $this->entityManager
     ->getRepository(UserGroup::class)
     ->findAll();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);

$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
     return $object->getId();
});

$encoder = new JsonEncoder();
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));

$groups = $serializer->serialize($groups, 'json');
return View::create(json_decode($groups, true), Response::HTTP_OK);
```

[output](https://pastebin.com/v5qsaH5g)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `@Groups()` annotation to specify which properties of your objects you want to serialize depending on the context.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups

So when you serialize your object, pass an array with the groups

```
$groups = $serializer->serialize($groups, 'json', ['groups' => 'user_groups.index']);
```

And in your entity, you add the group to the properties you want to be included

```
 Entity/UserGroup
 ---------------
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userGroups")
  * @Groups({"user_groups.index"})
  */
  private $users;
```